# How to use same custom text string for multiple Grails constraint messages in .properties files to avoid duplication

Tags: grails, internationalization

We have a number of constraints for the same object that should result in the same error message to the user, but cannot see a way of sharing the  text.  This leads to smelly duplication. For example:

**myInternationalizedProps_en.properties**

```
myClassName.propertyName.minSize.notmet = your entry must be between 6 and 10 characters
myClassName.propertyName.maxSize.notmet = your entry must be between 6 and 10 characters
```

Any way to collapse these into a single entry?  Using Grails 2.3.x

Comment: min and max are two different failures so unless you fail it manually and define own custom error: so when val.size() < minSize return and when val.size() > maxSize return  errors.rejectValue(propertyName,"minSize.notmet ",[''] as Object[],'')https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/blob/master/src/groovy/testing/ConnBean.groovy

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no". There's no way to use a message for different types of constraints. However for the particular case shown in your example, you could replace the `minSize` and `maxSize` constraints (and messages) with a single `size` constraint (and message).